# Paraview: How to draw arrow in a point cloud

Tags: paraview

I would like to know if paraview can manage this scenario:

I have a .txt file composed for this fields:
x y z vx vy vz

The first 3 parameters represents the location of the point in the space. The last 3 parameters are the components of the unit vector that represents a direction.

I would like to display the point cloud and for each point display the arrow that indicates indicates a direction using (vx,vy,vz)

I am sorry if it is a basic question, I recently started using paraview and I am a litle bit lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ParaView is the perfect tools for this task.

- Open ParaView
- Open File -> youFile.txt
- change the "delimiter" to " "
- set haveHeaders correctly if you have header or not in your file
- Apply
- Filters->TableToPoints
- X -> x, Y -> y, Z -> z (considering your file has headers)
- Apply
- Filters->Calculator -> `xv*iHat+yx*jHat+zv*kHat`, Apply
- Filters->Glyph
- GlyphMode property-> All Point , Apply
- Done !

Comment: Thanks Mathieu. It is working! But I have some issues. For instance some of my points does not have a unit vector specified, then this 3d points in the vx,vy,vz fileds have 0 values. It could be done that paraview ignore this points in order to no display an arrow? On the other hand I would like to do another thing. In order to check if the arrows are properly display I have an other file with the same points but each point has a rgb value. It is possible to merge this files directly on paraview and display rgb and arrow at the same time?

Comment: If you have missing data, first check in the Information Tab of the Calculator filter that you have all your points, then check in the properties tab of the glyph filter that "Glyph Mode" is "All Points" and not "Uniform Variable Distribution"

Comment: No, I do not have missing data. I think I not explained the problem in a good way. What I mean is before display the vectors I want to filter some of them. Imagine I have the point x y z that have associated the vector vx= 0 vy =0 vz =1. I would like to filter this vector and only render the point and not the vector. Should be possible to this in paraview?

Comment: You will need to create a selection using Edit->FindData, then Use Extract Selection filter so you can display your point in a ifferent way.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you so much. Far as I saw these days paraview is a powerful tool. I find out that I can save the "state" and use it for a different files. (awesome feature) I would like to ask you, it is possible to use this state via python? Can you recommend me some material in order to learn how to use the python interfaces of paraview?

Comment: Of course, use the `LoadState` python command in pvpython or the python shell. More info here : https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Python_Scripting and here https://www.paraview.org/ParaView/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/paraview.simple.html. FYI there is also ParaView (physical) course available at https://www.kitware.com/.